# Key on a string: double pendulum & consequences of not using a bob on a string?

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

While trying to do an at home experiment about a single pendulum, I used a key on a rope and let it swing. I came to the conclusion that this could not be a single pendulum, because of the extra 'point of rotation', where the key was attached to the string. Does this hold true? Is it a double pendulum, and what are the consequences of not using a more traditional setup, where a point mass is suspended from the string?

Comment: @nielsnielsen Thanks for the welcoming attitude! I do think however that everybody has to start somewhere, don't ridicule someone for what they don't know, applaud them for asking questions and researching.

Comment: MegJo, I was being neither sarcastic nor nonwelcoming. I took your question seriously and sat down and started working it out, thought I got it right, and then discovered I had it wrong. I took two more attempts to model the system, as this is one of my special interests, and got it wrong a total of three times. At that point I discovered that I did not know how to correctly model the system and explain its behavior. And that is why I exclaimed that the question did not have a simple, easily-derived ("trivial") answer. it is an *excellent* question.

Comment: @nielsnielsen, My sincere apologies, I was slightly hesitant about asking my question here as it felt really intimidating. I was quite confident that this could have been a 'stupid' question, as it feels like this should be high school physics. I have already done plenty of research about it, but I can't wrap my head around it. I am genuinely sorry for calling you out, I went on the defensive as I was afraid of being called 'stupid'!!

Comment: I just had an idea: an extended object on the end of a string (not a rigid rod) can be modeled as a *yo-yo* and I am going to google yoyo dynamics right now and see what we get, this is exciting stuff- NN

Answer (score 0):

If the length of the string is much greater than the length of the key then it can be modelled fairly accurately by the equations for a simple pendulum in most situations. If the length of the string is comparable to the length of the key then it can be modelled fairly accurately by the equations for a rigid double pendulum in most situations (so long as the differences in mass/unit-length for the string and key are taken into account).

But my caveat of 'most situations' is because both the simple pendulum and double pendulum equations are only approximations to reality. Even if you remove 'side-effects' such as mass and elasticity of the string, air resistance, and finite mass distribution within the bob by using a very thin inelastic string, a small dense bob (as a true point mass doesn't exist in reality), and operate in a vacuum, the actual motion of the pendulum will not be perfect harmonic motion because the restoring force on the bob (as a function of angular displacement $theta$) is proportional to $sin(theta)$ rather than to $theta$ - and harmonic motion is only an approximation to that. In practice, there is no analytic solution to the motion of any pendulum except in the limit where maximum displacement tends to zero.

Conclusion is, physics in reality can be complicated.